# WebGL rectangle borders

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, webgl

I'm trying to render a transparent rectangle with a solid border using WebGL. I know how to make it transparent by setting the alpha to zero in webGL's uniformfv() function but I can't figure out how to render a solid border and didn't find anything online that was helpful. Please note that I need to use WebGL, so context2D functions (e.g. strokeStyle) will probably not work. Please let me know if you know how to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The triangle primitives do not give you this ... however there is a gl.LINES as in

```
gl.drawElements(gl.LINES, given_animal.vertex_indices_buffer.numItems, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
```

so you could define your line segments as you circumnavigate about each triangle's vertices.  This primitive does have the notion of line width

```
gl.lineWidth(width);
```